# Android SDK Sample Error

Tags: android

I have imported the Android SDK samples via the Android wizard. But I'm getting errors shown below:
[image]

I've confirmed that my Java is 1.6 (I've changed it to 1.5 and back), but to no avail:
[image]

Please let me know if there is anything else I can do!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are missing android support library jar, you can add this library to you project by Right Click on your project -> Android Tools -> Add Support Library

[image]

Comment: awesome that worked!!! thanks so much.

weird that it didnt include it from the start